# How might I go about linking databases of business records to ratings data (such as yelp or google places)?

Tags: data-request, api, uses-of-open-data

Given a large database of business names and addresses, how might I go about pulling ratings for those entities from other accessible online data sources OR from the BBB, Yelp, or Google Places?

Answer (score 2):

BBB &Yelp both have Apis available

https://developer.bbb.org
https://www.yelp.com/developers